# If \section is followed by a \subsection, should there be nothing in between?

Tags: sectioning, best-practices

If `\section` is followed by a `\subsection`, should there be nothing in between?

> ### 2.1 The art of the bla
>
> some text
>
> #### 2.1.1 The details of
>   bla
>
> blaaaa
>
> #### 2.1.2 Further details of bla
>
> blaaaaaaaaaa

Is "some text" allowed there? What's considered "best practice" in TeX ?

(I know from *some* uni theses guides, "some text" would *not* be considered good practice). Also, does the dot of the previous sentence belong inside or outside the closing bracket?

Comment: This has nothing to do with TeX, but only with writing style. In general I'd suggest to explain the subject of the section before starting to develop it in subsections.

Comment: Perhaps [Graphics Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) would be a better place to ask for this?

Answer (score 3):

**There's no technical reason to disallow text inbetween.**

Everything else is a matter of personal preferences (or by some given guidelines).

Personally, I don't like "empty" structure elements. Text between `\section` and the first of several `\subsection`'s should, IMHO, give some "abstract" of the whole section. Same holds for the beginning of a `\chapter` followed by several sections.

Also, I think, that there shouldn't be single "sub-levels": A part should have either none or *more than one* chapter. A chapter either none or *more than one* sections. A section either none or *more than one* subsections.

These are, by the way, also the common guidelines by most Wikipedia's.

Comment: As [Foo Bar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19287/foo-bar) and @[vonbrand](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21275/vonbrand) says, nothing technical is said about this, but I also prefer to but some kind of text in between.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of taste... I personally add *some text* (a short introduction/overview of what comes) there. In the case of a `\chapter{}` followed immediately by a `\section{}` I'm not so sure, I've seen books that I like doing it both ways. When I write I place something in between (chapter introduction, at least).

[As you can see, I *hate* headings following one another with nothing in between. I'm not aware of guidelines one way or the other, so I'm eagerly awaiting the comments/autoritative answers tearing this one to shreds...]